# Update a table that has partition key and sort key using aws dynamodb and nodejs

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Using nodejs and dynamodb I am trying to update a table that has partition key and sort key but I am getting different errors, my code is this:

```js
static update = async (event: UserLocationModel) => {
        try {
            const timestamp: number = new Date().getTime();
            event.updatedAt = timestamp;

            let _event:UserLocationModel = Object.assign({}, event);
            let _userLocationId:number = _event.userLocationId;
            let _userName:string = _event.userName;
            
            let params = {
                TableName: process.env.TABLEUSERLOCATION,
                Key: { userLocationId: _userLocationId, userName: _userName },
                UpdateExpression: 'SET ',
                ExpressionAttributeNames: {},
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {}
            }

            delete event.userLocationId;
            delete event.userName;
            let keys = Object.keys(event);

            keys.map((key) => {
                params.ExpressionAttributeNames['#' + key] = key
                params.ExpressionAttributeValues[':' + key] = event[key]
                params.UpdateExpression = params.UpdateExpression + ` #${key} = :${key},`
            })
            params.UpdateExpression = params.UpdateExpression.slice(0, -1);

            await dynamodb.update(params).promise();

            return event;
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    };
```

The request:

```js
{
    "userLocationId": 1708285007269,
    "userName": "david@gmail.com",
    "createdAt": 1708285007269,
    "placeId": "ChIJvZ7phc9hRI4RmJZc8Prn1_E",
    "favorite": true,
    "color": "555"
}
```

When I make the call from Postman to perform the update, I get the following error:

`Invalid KeyConditionExpression: An expression attribute value used in expression is not defined; attribute value: :userName`

Then I delete the line `delete event.userName;` to include `userName`in the model, and I get the following error:

`One or more parameter values were invalid: Cannot update attribute userName. This attribute is part of the key`

So, I try to include `:userName` only in `ExpressionAttributeValues` as suggested by the first error, but I get this error:

`Value provided in ExpressionAttributeValues unused in expressions: keys: {:userName}`

How I could make this update ?

Thank you !!

How I could make this update ?

Thank you !!